# Can the Mirror of Erised be fooled?

Tags: harry-potter

The Mirror of Erised shows the viewer the deepest of their desires. It was used by Dumbledore in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's(Sorcerer's) Stone* to hide the Philosopher's(Sorcerer's) stone.

Quirrell could not retrieve the stone from the mirror as he wanted to use the stone, not to find it. It has been [suggested](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54054/79913) that Quirrell could have been successful if he had manipulated his own thoughts.

But how could this have worked? Wouldn't his *real* desire still be the same? Has it been mentioned officially that the mirror can be fooled this way?

Comment: It took me the longest time to realize that "Erised" is "Desire" backwards, i.e. *mirrored.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possibility is the [Confundus Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Confundus_Charm), mentioned canonically as a strong possibility as to how the Goblet of Fire was fooled into accepting Harry's name.

Answer (score 9):

## Maybe, especially using Occlumency to hide what’s truly desired.

I don't think so, but it might theoretically be possible. There's no official word on whether the Mirror of Erised could be fooled. But it may be possible. Using Occlumency to hide someone's true desires from the Mirror of Erised might have worked. It can shut down feelings and memories that show something is a lie, and this may work to hide the truth from the Mirror of Erised as well.

> “The Dark Lord, for instance, almost always knows when somebody is lying to him. Only those skilled at Occlumency are able to shut down those feelings and memories that contradict the lie, and so can utter falsehoods in his presence without detection.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24 (Occlumency)*</sup></sub>

Quirrell didn't know that the Mirror would have only worked for someone who wanted to find but not use the Philosopher's Stone, and no one else who looks into the Mirror has any reason to hide their true desire. (Dumbledore was able to keep his secret from Harry in a much simpler way - lying and saying he saw socks.)

Occlumency has fooled some very powerful wizards over the course of the seven books. Severus Snape was able to keep his true intentions secret from the Dark Lord for years. A few moments looking into a mirror would be relatively easy for someone skilled in Occlumency. This might not have helped Quirrell, because it's not known whether he could use Occlumency, but it definitely could be possible.

Comment: Even if Quirrell himself couldn't, we know that Voldy is talented at both Legilimency _and_ Occlumency.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Yes, good point. Had the Dark Lord known or suspected how the spell on the Mirror worked, he may have been able to retrieve the Stone with his own thoughts, using Quirrell as only a vessel for himself.

Comment: This is an interesting use of Occlumency. I didn't think it would apply to objects.

Comment: @GoodDeeds With the information we have, we don't know if it would or not. It's also possible that Occlumency wouldn't work on the Mirror of Erised. From what we know, it really can't be determined either way. However, using Occlumency is a very effective way of hiding your thoughts, so it's probably one of the best choices for trying to fool the Mirror.

Comment: Occlumency is used to hide your own thoughts/motivations/mind. As such, maybe it would be enough to block the mirror from finding your deepest desire. *But* the _key_ was not that the mirror didn't show you _using: the stone but that it showed you _finding_ it. If you managed to use occlumency to shield from the mirror, I would expect it to be blank (not a bad thing if you wanted to avoid getting hooked to it).

Comment: @Ángel Presumably someone talented enough in Occlumency would not only be able to hide their true thoughts, but also show other thoughts in their place. If every time the Dark Lord had looked into Snape's mind, he saw blankness, he would have probably been far more suspicious. So it must be possible to use Occlumency in a way that isn't just making your mind look blank.

Comment: In fact, given just how good Voldy was at Legilimency, what he could have done was implant a false vision in Quirrell's mind for the Mirror to read, which would then allow him to get the stone.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Yes, that could definitely have worked. Lord Voldemort would certainly have been able to do it, since he was able to make Harry see him having Sirius at the Ministry.